# How to render an Agora.io feed to a WebCamtexture in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, streaming, rendering, agora.io, texture2d

How should I implement the conversion?

As far as I got, the **VideoSurface.cs** contains all the rendering and texture code. From there it seems like the texture used in Agora.io is Texture2D, which is a private variable.

[image: private variable]

The only solution I found was the ***Graphics.Blit*** function and making the Texture2D variable public to access it, but I don't know whether if it will work or not, because it would mean a lot of rewrite to try and I would like to go with the most possibly successful route forward.

The best solution would be to not even use this Agora.io rendering, but rather render the incoming videostream directly to a WebCamTexture, without the need to copy the textures.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you need to convert the incoming video stream to a WebcamTexture.  My understanding of a WebcamTexture is the holding your local camera's stream, usually people want to grab the data from it and send out, not the other way around.  Would you share your code how you plan to set the data there?

However, to answer your original question - if you want to render own texture display, please use of VideoRawDataManager without the VideoSurface script.